# GWT Editor bug?

Tags: gwt

This is my development environment :

- ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- Eclipse Version: 3.7.2 (Indigo)
- Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7
- Google Web Toolkit 2.4.0
- GWT Designer Core 2.5.0
- GWT Designer GPE 2.5.0
- WindowBuilder Core 1.3.0
- WindowBuilder CSS Support 1.2.0
- WindowBuilder XML Core 1.3.0

I created a gwt/app engine project with the "App Engine Connected Android Project" and made very modifications (just refactoring a few names).

When I click on my "ui.xml" gwt file, I can display it in the Eclipse editor window "XML Source" tab.

But when I click on the "Design" tab, I get the following error :

```
Internal Error

encountered unexpected internal error.

This could be caused by a bug or by a misconfiguration issue, conflict, partial update, etc.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/proxy/Callback
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.cglib.proxy.Callback
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.model.EditorContext.<init>(EditorContext.java:59)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.uibinder.parser.UiBinderContext.<init>(UiBinderContext.java:89)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.uibinder.editor.UiBinderDesignPage.parse(UiBinderDesignPage.java:101)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(XmlDesignPage.java:451)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage.access$2(XmlDesignPage.java:443)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage$7$1.run(XmlDesignPage.java:417)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4330)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage$7.run(XmlDesignPage.java:414)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:507)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage.internal_refreshGEF_withProgress(XmlDesignPage.java:435)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(XmlDesignPage.java:388)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.UndoManager.refreshDesignerEditor(UndoManager.java:252)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage.updateGEF(XmlDesignPage.java:361)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage.refreshGEF(XmlDesignPage.java:354)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.actions.RefreshAction.run(RefreshAction.java:47)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.actions.DesignPageAction.run(DesignPageAction.java:35)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlExceptionComposite.doRefresh(XmlExceptionComposite.java:65)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.errors.ExceptionComposite$3.widgetSelected(ExceptionComposite.java:129)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3588)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3209)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Full context stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/proxy/Callback
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.model.EditorContext.<init>(EditorContext.java:59)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.uibinder.parser.UiBinderContext.<init>(UiBinderContext.java:89)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.uibinder.editor.UiBinderDesignPage.parse(UiBinderDesignPage.java:101)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(XmlDesignPage.java:451)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage.access$2(XmlDesignPage.java:443)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage$7$1.run(XmlDesignPage.java:417)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4330)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage$7.run(XmlDesignPage.java:414)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:507)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage.internal_refreshGEF_withProgress(XmlDesignPage.java:435)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(XmlDesignPage.java:388)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.UndoManager.refreshDesignerEditor(UndoManager.java:252)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage.updateGEF(XmlDesignPage.java:361)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage.refreshGEF(XmlDesignPage.java:354)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.actions.RefreshAction.run(RefreshAction.java:47)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.actions.DesignPageAction.run(DesignPageAction.java:35)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlExceptionComposite.doRefresh(XmlExceptionComposite.java:65)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.errors.ExceptionComposite$3.widgetSelected(ExceptionComposite.java:129)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3588)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3209)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.cglib.proxy.Callback
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 48 more
```

Answer (score 1):

The important line in your stacktrace is:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.cglib.proxy.Callback

Apparently somewhere in your GWT code you reference the `Callback`class from the `net.sf.cglib.proxy`package.
If you reference any package or class in your GWT code you must have the source code in order for the GWT compiler to be able to translate it to javascript.

However this `net.sf.cglib.proxy`package belongs to the cglib.jar which is a Bytecode manipulation library. 
This library is not supported in GWT.
Check your source code for references to `net.sf.cglib.proxy.Callback`.
I assume you imported the wrong package.

Comment: The beginning of my code is : <ui:UiBinder
    xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>. Maybe I am wrong, but I didn't find any reference to the net.sf.cglib.proxy package

Comment: check your java file for any references.

Comment: Sorry about this. I installed the GWT Designer (http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/3.7) and I'm able now to open the "Design" tab.